# Use IntelliJ to generate class diagram

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml, class-diagram

How do I get IntelliJ 10.5 (on the Mac) to generate a class diagram showing all of the classes in my project?  I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can only get the "Show Diagram" feature to show one class at a time.  (I also figured out how to add additional classes, but again, only one at a time.)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Use `Diagrams` | `Show Diagram...` from the context menu of a package. Invoking it on the project root will show module dependencies diagram.

If you need multiple packages, you can drag & drop them to the already opened diagram for the first package and press <kbd>e</kbd> to expand it.

**Note**: This feature is available in the Ultimate Edition, not the free Community Edition.

Comment: Does this mean there's no plugins available for community version to generate class diagram, now and in the future?

Comment: @BruceSun not at the moment

Comment: @CrazyCoder How do you use this to view a UML diagram for a class and it's edges, .. i am thinking find my nodes, dept 3 ... or all ... right now its pretty useless. it only shows class hiearchies, not what object it uses, and what those object in turn uses. This uml plugin is not useful.

Comment: Link down :-( could you fix it please?

Comment: Upvote for the 'Note' part.

Answer (score 76):

**IntelliJ IDEA 14+**

- Show diagram popup

  **Right click on a type/class/package > Diagrams > Show Diagram Popup...**
  or 
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- Show diagram (opens a new tab)

  **Right click on a type/class/package > Diagrams > Show Diagram...**
  or 
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

  [image: right click Diagrams Show Diagram]

By default, you see only the classes/interfaces names. If you want to see more details, go to **File > Settings... > Tools > Diagrams** and check what you want (E.g.: Fields, Methods, etc.)

---

**P.S.:** You need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, because this feature is not supported in Community Edition. If you go to File > Settings... > Plugins, you can see that there is not UML Support plugin in Community Edition.

Comment: Hi guys, I am using Intellij 15.0.2 and I want to view class diagram of my project, however I can not see the selection Diagrams/Show Diagram when I right click in a package or a class. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Ectoras , I suppose that you use Community Edition, not Ultimate. It is not available for Community Edition (see the P.S.: added in the post). I tested it in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2 Ultimate and it worked.

Answer (score 66):

You can install one of the free pugins - [Code Iris](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7324?pr=idea).
[image]

[PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/)

[image]

Other tools of this type in the IntelliJ IDEA are paid.

---

I chose a more powerful alternative: 
In Netbeans - [easyUML](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55435/easyuml)
In Eclipse - [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/), [Papyrus](https://eclipse.org/papyrus/), [Eclipse Modeling Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/lunasr1a)

[image]

I hope it will help you.

Comment: `Code Iris` just stops my project to launch. Community version 2019.1.

Comment: @WesternGun i'm not surprised man. This tool with 3 stars rating...

Comment: I installed PlantUML plugin, but do not know how to get started and use it. Please add that also

Comment: looks like PlantUML is used to create class diagrams? I did not see any use case/instructions online where it can be used to generate class diagrams automatically.

Answer (score 17):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Also check if the UML plugin is activated (settings -> plugin, settings can be opened by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

Use Intellij plugin [Sketch It!](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10387-sketch-it-).

[image: Class Diagram generated with Sketch It! plugin]

Comment: ...which needs PlantUML plugin to visualize the diagram. With Community version 2019.1 it works, after installing Graphviz and adding `bin` to PATH. Windows 10. But, it only renders relationship in each package, not in the whole projects, thing that I expected, but thanks anyway.

Comment: sketch It is an amazing tool :》thanks

Comment: @alen, I tried using Sketch It, but the plugin throws an error. How did you get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Now there is an official way to add "**[PlantUML integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration)**" plugin to your JetBrains product.

Installation steps please refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387418/5320704

Answer (score 0):

this plugin is really good: [Sketch It!.](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10387-sketch-it-)