# Drawing Uml Diagram of java classes

Tags: uml

I try to draw Uml Diagrams of a java classes at a package at runtime. 
I am using İntelj İdea. 
**How can draw the Uml diagram with java code?**

Comment: This may be your answer: [Use IntelliJ to generate class diagram][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942751/use-intellij-to-generate-class-diagram

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA supports UML to/from Java code.  Read about it here:
[UML Designer](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_designer.html)

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I want to draw UML Diagram of any class with help of any package.