# "UML Support" Plugin for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, intellij-14

I must be missing something. I am reading [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-diagrams.html) and it says that there is a plugin called "UML Support" which is enabled by default. I didn't have it, so I went to Preferences > Plugins and see no such plugin. Searching didn't show it as well.

[This page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-class-hierarchy-as-a-class-diagram.html) which is a sub-page of the previous one says I should be able to press <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and a diagram will come up. That doesn't work, and I also don't see a Diagram > Show Diagram on any context menu for my files in the project.

How can I see UML Diagrams of my codebase? It looks like it should be straightforward but I don't see any of these in Intellij 14.1.4

Comment: I don't know this Tool, but looking at the features-page I realize, that this feature is greyed out by switching to the community-edition tab. So you should maybe make sure to use the enterprise edition?

Comment: Someone had a similar question in a comment from here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26926334/3885376) for IntellIJ IDEA 15 and I tested it in both of them (Ultimate and Community Edition). **Community  Edition doesn't have this feature**.

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer - the alternative is to use a uml plugin with community edition.

Answer (score 27):

You can install the free plugin - [Code Iris](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7324?pr=idea).
[image]

I use [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/)  for creating diagrams

[image]

Other tools of this type in the IntelliJ IDEA are paid.

---

I chose a more powerful alternative: 
In Netbeans - [easyUML](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55435/easyuml)
In Eclipse - [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/), [Papyrus](https://eclipse.org/papyrus/), [Eclipse Modeling Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/lunasr1a)

[image]

Comment: +1 for PlantUML. Just in case the instructions weren't clear, install the PlantUML Integration plugin in IntelliJ, and then install PlantUML and GraphViz (if you are on Mac its easiest to install them through HomeBrew)

Comment: What instructions?

Comment: In 2020, is Plant UML still one of the best UML plugins for the community edition ? There are other UML plugins like simpleUML also which have been downloaded by several thousand people.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev checkout when was last update for this plugin and you will answer your question

Comment: @ArtemSolovev - Thanks, I understood it. But the problem with Plant UML is that we have to type the description of the class as a comment so that plant uml can draw our class diagrams. Is there any tool or plugin which draws the class diagram without any extra effort ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev There is no easy way to make good things. If you will find one let us know. Or make it by yourself - it will be helpful

Comment: @ArtemSolovev - Please spare me the sarcasm and the extra advice. There is already a paid version of Intellij IDEA with UML. I can't afford to buy that now, especially just for one plugin.

Comment: I don't get the usecase of PlantUML. I have to type normal source code and on top of it, type UML just so PlantUML can show it. Hope there was a free plugin which just scans all our java code and makes UML diagram automatically. I mean java is a typed language after all.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to install PlantUML plugin to JetBrains product(IntelliJ, Webstrom, Pycharm), you need to

1. download plugins from official website in .zip format: 
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration
2. go to "File -> Settings -> Plugins" and choose "install plugin from disk"
3. choose the downloaded file and select Restart (WebStorm etc.)

After the installation you could open your UML view from "View -> Tool Windows -> PlantUML"

[image]

Comment: In 2020, is Plant UML still one of the best UML plugins for the community edition ? There are other UML plugins like simpleUML also which have been downloaded by several thousand people.

Comment: I dont know about simpleUML. Anyway I found the lastest update of simpleUML plugin by JetBrains was on 2007 and got 3.5/5 votes, while plantUML has lastest update on oct. 2019 with 5/5 votes.

Comment: But the problem with Plant UML is that we have to type the description of the class as a comment so that plant uml can draw our class diagrams. Is there any tool or plugin which draws the class diagram without any extra effort ?

Comment: To draw a class diagram need to follow the class diagram grammer (https://plantuml.com/en/class-diagram). I am not quite sure what "description of the class as a comment" means, but I think plantUML needs just the necessary parts of class information:).

Comment: We have to type all the class information as a comment between `/*@startuml ... @enduml*/`. I was wondering if there is any tool or plugin in which we don't need to type anything. The tool should inspect the classes & generate the UML diagrams automatically for us.

Comment: To generate a PlantUML file from existing Java code, you can use this tool: 
http://plantuml-depend.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

Only the ultimate version has the 'UML Support' plugin.
This plugin is not free.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html

Comment: To get the UML diagram generation feature, you have to pay for the Ultimate version of IntelliJ.

The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html) in 2019 explicitely states this now:

> This feature is only supported in the Ultimate edition.

The question is from 2015 however.
I don't know why was your answer down voted; I think it implicitely answered the question.

Comment: @onetom Thank you very much.I have found the same answer as your.You explain it more clearer than me.