# Tools to diagram the sources of a Codename One app

Tags: codenameone

A stakeholder asked me diagrams that explains how the source code of a Codename One app I’m writing works. It’s a generic question about diagrams... and it seems mission impossible to do by hand: currently I’ve already written about 50k lines of code for this app... Do you know any automatic tool that works fine with the sources of a Codename One app to make printable diagrams (any type of diagram that helps to understand how the code works)?

Thank you

Comment: I haven't used those in years as they don't explain as much. Back in the day the netbeans diagram tools worked. However, I think you might be better off grabbing diagrams from my books free chapters here: https://uber.cn1.co/ there are a few high level diagrams that explain things way better than UML e.g. pages 27, 28, 29, 38, 46/7 (layout managers) etc.

Comment: Thank you Shai, the diagrams in your book are a good starting point to try to explain how the code works. I've just also seen few other interesting high level diagrams in the full version of your book.

Comment: If you need higher quality source images of the diagrams just send me a low quality scan of the image and I'll try and locate the source image in my materials.

Comment: Thank you very much: it’s not necessary, Gimp allowed me to export images at 300 dpi, that is a good quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language is Java, then you can have a lot of UML makers out there

[Use IntelliJ to generate class diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942751/use-intellij-to-generate-class-diagram) will help if you are using an IDE.