# how to creat class diagram from java project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a method you would recommend to ***create the class diagram (uml) of my java project*** in IntelliJ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use IntelliJ to generate class diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942751/use-intellij-to-generate-class-diagram)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a method in IntelliJ.
If you select you package file and right click on it and select Diagrams, after that select the Show diagram options. After that click on Java Classes Diagram.
If you want to show more details right click on the corresponding package, and select.
[This is the package] -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRHjT.png 
[This is the second step]-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fcNg.png 
[This is the last step] -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/szHOt.png 
[This is how you show more details] -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYx5H.png